# CompactMapValues not working on this simple dictionary

Tags: swift, struct, swift-optionals

I have a model that looks like:

```
public struct Profile {
  public let bio: String?
  public let company: String
  public let createdDate: Date
  public let department: String
  public let email: String
  public let firstName: String
  public let coverImageURL: URL?
  public let jobTitle: String
  public let lastName: String
  public let location: String?
  public let name: String
  public let profileImageURL: URL?
  public let roles: [String]
  public let isActive: Bool
  public let updatedDate: Date?
  public let userID: String

  public init(
    bio: String?, company: String, createdDate: Date, department: String, email: String, firstName: String, coverImageURL: URL?, jobTitle: String,
    lastName: String, location: String?, name: String, profileImageURL: URL?, roles: [String], isActive: Bool, updatedDate: Date?, userID: String) {
    self.bio = bio
    self.company = company
    self.createdDate = createdDate
    self.department = department
    self.email = email
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.coverImageURL = coverImageURL
    self.jobTitle = jobTitle
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.location = location
    self.name = name
    self.profileImageURL = profileImageURL
    self.roles = roles
    self.isActive = isActive
    self.updatedDate = updatedDate
    self.userID = userID
  }


}

extension Profile: Equatable { }
```

I am trying to create a tuple that represents it as `(model: Profile, json: [String: Any])`

using the following method -

```
  func makeProfile() -> (model: Profile, json: [String: Any]) {

    let updatedDate = Date()
    let updatedDateStr = updatedDate.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX")
    let createdDate = Date()
    let createdDateStr = createdDate.toString(dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXXXX")

    let coverImageURL = makeURL("https://headerUri.com")
    let profileImageURL = makeURL("https://pictureUri.com")
    let model = Profile(
      bio: "Some Bio",
      company: "Cool Job INC",
      createdDate: createdDate,
      department: "Engineering",
      email: "name@domain.tld",
      firstName: "Anne",
      coverImageURL: coverImageURL,
      jobTitle: "Test Dummy",
      lastName: "Employee",
      location: "London",
      name: "Anne Employee",
      profileImageURL: profileImageURL,
      roles: ["ADMIN"],
      isActive: true,
      updatedDate: updatedDate,
      userID: UUID().uuidString
    )

    let json: [String: Any] = [
      "bio": model.bio,
      "company": model.company,
      "createdDate": createdDateStr,
      "department": model.department,
      "email": model.email,
      "firstName": model.firstName,
      "headerUri": model.coverImageURL?.absoluteString,
      "jobTitle": model.jobTitle,
      "lastName": model.lastName,
      "location": model.location,
      "name": model.name,
      "pictureUri": model.profileImageURL?.absoluteString,
      "roles": model.roles,
      "isActive": model.isActive,
      "updatedDate": updatedDateStr,
      "userId": model.userID
      ].compactMapValues { $0 }

    return (model: model, json: json)
  }
}

extension Date {
  func toString(dateFormat format: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
    return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
  }
}
```

All of the optional properties are showing a warning `Expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to 'Any'`

[image]

I have added `.compactMapValues { $0 }` to the dict but has had no effect.

How can I clear this warning?

Comment: Swift gives you multiple ways to fix this in the warning message.

Comment: Yes, but I shouldn't need to provide a default value or cast as `Any` as `compactMapValues` should filter the nil properties.

Comment: Unrelated but you can delete the `init` method in `Profile`. You get it for free.

Comment: `compactMapValues` does that at run-time, but there's no guarantee at compile-time that the value is not nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because you trying to implicitly coerce an optional value (which could be nil) to `Any`, which hides that the value could be nil.

`compactMapValues` doesn't guarantee at compile-time that the value is not nil; all the compiler knows is that something that is an optional (like `String?`) is now treated as a non-optional `Any`.

One way you could avoid the error is by providing a default value instead of the optional:

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
   "bio": model.bio ?? ""
    // ...
   ]
```

Alternatively, you can create a dictionary of: `[String, Any?]` to assign values to, and then use `.compactMapValues`, which would give you back non-optional values of `Any`.

```
let withOptionals: [String: Any?] = [
   "bio": model.bio,
   // ...
]

let json: [String, Any] = withOptionals.compactMapValues { $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the warning because the values are optional *when you initialize the dictionary*. Your `.compactMapValues { $0 }` won't help because by then it's "too late".

Instead you could initialize an empty dictionary and add the values 1 by 1.

```
var json = [String: Any]()
json["bio"] = model.bio
json["company"] = model.company
// all of the other values
json["userId"] = model.userID
```